# How to force declaring function constructor properties in JavaScript (ES5) before their use?

Tags: javascript, variables, constructor, properties, ecmascript-5

This question may contain answer, I was thinking about possible solutions to that. However, I would like to know, if (and how) someone had done it in better way.

The problem is, that I have really long function constructors and the whole instance of that function contains lot of properties and so I try to 'initialize' these properties on the very beggining of the function constructor, because I would like to exactly know, what is used and assure myself, that there are no new declaration of properties somewhere in the middle of the code.

I know, that it is quite simple, when we think about 'normal' variables, when we "use strict":

```
"use strict"

favouriteAnimal = 'honeybadger'; //Uncaught ReferenceError: favouriteAnimal is not defined
```

This will throw and Error, because we haven't used:

```
"use strict"

const favouriteAnimal = 'porcupine';
```

or

```
"use strict"

var favouriteAnimal = null //or let
favouriteAnimal = 'aardvark';
```

*In these following scenarios, please notice the 'this.importantFunction' and 'this.favouriteAnimal'. The rest of constructor function only demonstrates slightly complicated object structure, which would benefit from such early variable (property) definition.*

But the struggle beggins within Objects, in following scenario, this is what is typically done, it is working, but it does not offer such safety precautions as to force us defining all variables first.

```
function TypicalContructorFunction1 ()
{
    this.someRandomFunctionWithoutRealPurpose = function () {
        console.warn('someone really used me?');
    }

    this.someStuff = 'coffee break';
    this.differentStuff = 'broken coffee';

    this.importantFunction = function (animalName) {
        this.favouriteAnimal = animalName;
    };

    this.importantFunction('sewer rat');

    return this;
};

var typicalObject1 = new TypicalContructorFunction1();
console.log(typicalObject1.favouriteAnimal)
```

Console will log an Object with property 'favouriteAnimal', but as the object structure is slightly fatter and so it is not clearly visible, that such property was defined.

Another approach with 'helping' function:

```
function useProperty (object, propertyName, closure) {

    if (object && typeof object[propertyName] !== 'undefined') {
        closure(object[propertyName], object, propertyName);
    } else {
        throw new ReferenceError('property "' + propertyName + '" not declared');
    }
};

const TypicalContructorFunction2 = function ()
{
    this.someRandomFunctionWithoutRealPurpose = function () {
        console.warn('someone really used me?');
    }

    this.someStuff = 'coffee break';
    this.differentStuff = 'broken coffee';

    this.importantFunction = function (animalName) {
        useProperty(this, 'favouriteAnimal', function (property)
        {
            property = animalName;
        });
    };

    this.importantFunction('drosophila melanogaster');

    return this;
};

var typicalObject2 = new TypicalContructorFunction2();
```

There is no need for console.log, because new ReferenceError will be thrown and execution stopped, which is what I want. However, this calling a function, passing a function to just change a simple value seems a bit as overkilling and I think, that it may have performance drawbacks too.

And as last (but not least) I came up with sealing the object after declaring all properties, so there cannot be added any other properties. *(needs "use strict")*

```
"use strict"
function TypicalContructorFunction3 ()
{

    this.someStuff = null;
    this.differentStuff = null;
    this.someRandomFunctionWithoutRealPurpose = null;
    this.importantFunction = null;

    Object.seal(this);

    this.someRandomFunctionWithoutRealPurpose = function () {
        console.warn('someone really used me?');
    }

    this.someStuff = 'coffee break';
    this.differentStuff = 'broken coffee';

    this.importantFunction = function (animalName) {
        this.favouriteAnimal = animalName;
    };

    this.importantFunction('jerboa');

    return this;
};

var test = new TypicalContructorFunction3();
```

*ReferenceError: property "favouriteAnimal" not declared*

I think, that this may be the answer, while it does not seal the object deeply (there would definitely be some code snippets with deep sealing on StackOverflow).

I also know, that I can still use var/const/let inside function, but such variables become private and cannot be accessed from outside of the function.

Have you come up with different solutions to this issue?

*PS: Please, this answer is asked for **ECMAScript v5**, as it is in the title.*
Thanks for ideas :)

Comment: As far as I know, class fields is a [very new thing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields) and you can't use them in ES5

Comment: This might not answer your question, but you can try keeping the data in a separate object like [so](https://jsfiddle.net/3ach0tkv/)

Comment: Yes, I sort data this way using IIFEs, which can populate (return) object easily without unnecessary leftovers. Still thanks for comments/caring :)